# Jetty 9 - ServerContainer attribute is missing in ServletContextListener

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to deploy a websocket endpoint during `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`.

When I try to get the ServerContainer null is returned.

`ServerContainer sc = (ServerContainer) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");
// sc == null`

In my java command I load the module `--module=websocket`.

BTW, when I used the jetty maven plugin on my local machine everything worked.

Comment: Run `$ cd /path/to/mybase && java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config` and report back the output (you can edit your question to include this output).

Comment: I was able to make it work by running a clean jetty distribution (e.g. not using any xml config/context files and putting my war file under the webapps folder).

I'll work my way back and post any conclusions.

Comment: If you are modifying the `jetty-distribution` you are using Jetty improperly.  Once you unpack `jetty-distribution` you should consider that directory read-only and not do a thing to it.  Create a separate `${jetty.base}` directory somewhere else (not within your `jetty-distribution`) and setup your instance configuration there.